# Suppose $M_n \rightarrow M$ in $L^1$ norm, then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_X(t)^{M_n} | M_n]] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_X(t)^{M} | M]]$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have two r.v. $M, X$ and some sequence of r.v. $(M_n)_n$ s.t. $M_n \rightarrow M$ in $L^1$ norm, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[|M_n - M|] \rightarrow 0$. I would now like to show that we also have:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_X(t)^{M_n} | M_n]] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_X(t)^{M} | M]],
$$
here $M_X(t)$ denotes the moment generating function of $X$ at $t$. I would guess that we can replace $M_X(t)$ by any value $x$ so we would like to show that for arbitrary $a$ we have:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[a^{M_n} | M_n]] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[a^{M} | M]],
$$
and we need to find a good bound on
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[a^{M_n} | M_n] - \mathbb{E}[a^{M} | M]]
$$
which does not seem too hard, but I don't really know how to get started.

Comment: First consider that $E[a^{M_n}]$ and $E[a^{M}]$ doesn't exist necessarily… so your question is not well defined. But if they do, it holds $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[a^{M_n} | M_n]] = \mathbb{E}[a^{M_n}]$$ and $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[a^{M} | M]] = \mathbb{E}[a^{M}]$$ by properties of conditional expectation hence you want to show $$\mathbb{E}[a^{M_n}] \to \mathbb{E}[a^{M}]$$
I doubt this holds but haven't found a counterexample yet, where $E[a^{M_n}]$ and $E[e^M]$ exists

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying, now I find my question rather silly!